# Which filetypes can be explicitly searched for in Google search?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I was surprised not to find any data in the following google search

```
US Politics filetype:csv
```

After some tinkering, I realised *any* search for `filetype:csv` will return 0 results!

In the past, searches with `filetype:csv` *would* return results. There's nothing wrong with the operator itself, just the value, e.g. a search with `filetype:pdf` *will* return results.

What is the full list of acceptable values for `filetype` operator in Google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### According to [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search), the entire list is:

- Adobe Acrobat PDF (.pdf)
- Adobe Postscript (.ps)
- Autodesk DWF (.dwf)
- Google Earth KML (.kml)
- Google Earth KMZ (.kmz)
- Microsoft Excel (.xls)
- Microsoft Powerpoint (.ppt)
- Microsoft Word (.doc)
- Rich Text Format (.rtf)
- Shockwave Flash (.swf)

Comment: + 1. That's a clever way of finding some/all of the valid values. Do you how we can tell if the list is exhaustive?

Comment: These seem to be the only values that are currently valid, after trying different common extensions like `.mp3` or `.ttf`.

Answer (score 1):

From [File Types Indexable by Google | Google Search Central  |  Documentation  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/indexable-file-types):

- Adobe Portable Document Format (.pdf)
- Adobe PostScript (.ps)
- Google Earth (.kml, .kmz)
- GPS eXchange Format (.gpx)
- Hancom Hanword (.hwp)
- HTML (.htm, .html, other file extensions)
- Microsoft Excel (.xls, .xlsx)
- Microsoft PowerPoint (.ppt, .pptx)
- Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
- OpenOffice presentation (.odp)
- OpenOffice spreadsheet (.ods)
- OpenOffice text (.odt)
- Rich Text Format (.rtf)
- Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)
- TeX/LaTeX (.tex)
- Text (.txt, .text, other file extensions), including source code in common programming languages:

  - Basic source code (.bas)
  - C/C++ source code (.c, .cc, .cpp, .cxx, .h, .hpp)
  - C# source code (.cs)
  - Java source code (.java)
  - Perl source code (.pl)
  - Python source code (.py)
- Wireless Markup Language (.wml, .wap)
- XML (.xml)

Comment: The way google's `filetype` search operator works is kinda weird. For example, if I search for `a filetype:abcdefg` I see some results, so it appears the `filetype` operator simply allows *anything* not just the extensions mentioned in Google's documentation. *But*, there appear to be exceptions. For example if I search `a filetype:csv` I see 0 results, because it appears google prevents searching for that `filetype`.  (Note, the reason for searching for 'a' in the examples is because it's a common term likely to yield results).

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any `filetype` you want, however google defaults to providing ***very*** limited results, and even blocks searches for some filetypes (e.g. `filetype:csv`).

To ensure your results are not limited, append `&filter=0` to the URL.

Here are some examples:

#### Using `&filter=0` to avoid limited results

A particular [search for python files](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+filetype%3Apy) gives 39 results:

[image]

but the [same search](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+filetype%3Apy&filter=0) with `&filter=0` added to the end of the URL gives over 20k times as many results:

[image]

#### Google does not allow all `filetype` values

Searching for `a filetype:csv` gives 0 results. JSON appears to the be same. I didn't find documentation on this but did come across others asking about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958479/google-filetypecsv-doesnt-show-results) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/5z2bq9/how_to_find_csvs_online/).

#### Google's filetype list isn't exhaustive

Google lists some *most common* file types ([here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/indexable-file-types)). But the list isn't exhaustive. You can search for any filetype (i.e. file extension) you wish.

For example [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+filetype:sdfsdf&filter=0) for `a filetype:sdfsdf` gives 17 results after the `&filter=0` is added:

[image]