# Google filetype:csv doesn't show results

Tags: google-search

I try to find some data sets using google, but typing some phrase (e.g. songs) and

```
filetype:csv
```

results nothing. What is the problem? I tried for `filetype:json`, and its the same. Using `filetype:txt` instead works. I was looking for some topics about it and find only some [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/5z2bq9/how_to_find_csvs_online/)

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't indexes `csv` files, so you should search for those datasets by querying websites exposing those data.

For some data sets about "songs" search on Google for `open data songs`.

The **key** here is to use the words "**open data**". It'll find some online data sets, some of them for free, and some of them for free commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

according to https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/indexable-file-types
**google is not indexing all file types.**

Google can index the content of most types of pages and files. The most common file types Google index include:

```
Adobe Portable Document Format (.pdf)
Adobe PostScript (.ps)
Google Earth (.kml, .kmz)
GPS eXchange Format (.gpx)
Hancom Hanword (.hwp)
HTML (.htm, .html, other file extensions)
Microsoft Excel (.xls, .xlsx)
Microsoft PowerPoint (.ppt, .pptx)
Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
OpenOffice presentation (.odp)
OpenOffice spreadsheet (.ods)
OpenOffice text (.odt)
Rich Text Format (.rtf)
Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)
TeX/LaTeX (.tex)
Text (.txt, .text, other file extensions), including source code in common programming languages:
Basic source code (.bas)
C/C++ source code (.c, .cc, .cpp, .cxx, .h, .hpp)
C# source code (.cs)
Java source code (.java)
Perl source code (.pl)
Python source code (.py)
Wireless Markup Language (.wml, .wap)
XML (.xml)
```